# Does $\mathbb E[f(X)]=\mathbb E[f(Y)]$ for all continuous function $\iff X\sim Y$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I know that $X\sim Y\iff \mathbb E[f(X)]=\mathbb E[f(Y)]$ for all bounded and measurable function $f$. Now I was wondering if $$X\sim Y\iff \mathbb E[f(X)]=\mathbb E[f(Y)],$$
for all $f$ continuous and bounded. So, what I tried to prove is $$\forall f\in \mathcal C_b(\mathbb R), \mathbb E[f(X)]=\mathbb E[f(Y)]$$ if and only if $$\mathbb E[f(X)]=\mathbb E[f(Y)],$$
for all measurable and bounded functions $f$.

So, the reverse implication is clear. But for the the implication, I tried as follow : $$\mathbb E[f(X)]=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\mu_X(dx).$$
So if $\mu_X$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, then there is $(f_n)$ continuous s.t. $f_n\to f$ in $L^2(\mathbb R,\mu_X)$. And thus $$\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\mu_X(dx)=\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{\mathbb R}f_n(x)\mu_X(dx)=\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{\mathbb R}f_n(y)\mu_Y(dy).$$

**Q1)** Does this last limit converge to $\int_{\mathbb R}f_n(y)\mu_Y(dy)$ ?

**Q2)** What happens if $\mu_X$ is not absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with measure theory, but what's wrong with choosing $f$ to be the indicator function for a certain value? That is, you can choose $f$ to return $1$ if its argument is $a$, and $0$ otherwise. Hence $\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \mathbb{P}(X = a)$, and this argument holds for all $a$, so the probability distributions are the same too.

Comment: It’s probably helpful to recall that $f$ can be approximated by simple functions, and the integral for the expected value can also be approximated with simple functions.

Comment: @paulinho For most random variables (i.e. the ones corresponding to continuous distributions), $P(X=a)=0$ for all $a\in\Bbb R$. Also, the indicator function of a point is not continuous.

Comment: (Q1) Can you use the dominated convergence theorem?  In that theorem, the dominating function has to be measurable, but I don't recall the conditions on the limit, and you are already assuming bounded. (Q2) Maybe use outer measure instead of Lebesgue when necessary?

Answer (score 1):

As you realize, your approach is going to be tricky if your measures $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ have different kinds of supports.

An obvious fix is to try and use the DCT: as long as the $f_n$ converge pointwise to $f$ and are uniformly bounded, there is no issue.

Of course, not every measurable function is a pointwise limit of continuous functions. This is why we do it in two steps:

First step: for every open subset $U$, $\mu_X(U)=\mu_Y(U)$.

Proof: Take $f=1_U$ and $f_n$ between $0$ and $1$ converging pointwise to $f$.

Second step: $\mu_X=\mu_Y$.

Proof: the collection $\mathcal{M}$ of Borel subsets $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu_X(S)=\mu_Y(S)$ is a monotone class containing all open subsets (which are stable under intersection). We then use the monotone class lemma.

Comment: I downvoted because "Of course, not every measurable function is a pointwise limit of continuous functions" is false in the a.e. sense, which is all that matters for integration.

Comment: @snar: I understand your point, but the subtlety with your argument is that you need an ae limit wrt simultaneously $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$. My argument avoids this trap.